# How to fill a column getting a substring of another one with a rule

Tags: microsoft-excel, string, string-manipulation, column

I'm trying to play with the functions LEFT, RIGHT and SEARCH to fill a column with the name of a function extracted from another column, but I don't get any good result.

I have a list of functions like the next:

```
def _handle_push(self, word)
def _handle_table_reset(self, word)
def _handle_sentinel(self, word)
def _handle_struct(self, word)
def _handle_define_table(self, word)
def _handle_debug(self, word)
def _handle_copy(self, word)
def _handle_end_row(self, word)
def _handle_placeholder_count(self, word)
def _handle_convert_mach_continuous(self, word)
```

And for example, If I take the first one

```
def _handle_push(self, word)
```

the result that I want to store in another column will be

```
_handle_push
```

But I don't know how to achieve this.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean something like `=IFERROR(MID(A1;FIND(" ";A1)+1;FIND("(";A1)-FIND(" ";A1)-1);"Not found")`?

Comment: Absolutly incredible. That's it. Thank you

Comment: You can also try [**Flash Fill**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-flash-fill-in-excel-4e8cda31-51a7-45b7-ad19-a050ecc63cc4): type `_handle_push` next to the first cell and press **Ctrl+E**. Or copy column and choose [**Data > Text to Columns**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7): set delimiters **Space** and **Other (**, on next step mark first and third to the end columns as **Skip**